# how to insert a list<Item> of items somewhere with Repeater

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

Suppose I have an Item which exposes a `items` property of type `list<Item>`, which now is set to:

```
items: [
    Rectangle {
        width: sz; height: sz
        color: 'red'
    },
    Rectangle {
        width: sz; height: sz
        color: 'green'
    },
    Rectangle {
        width: sz; height: sz
        color: 'blue'
    }
]
```

how to instantiate that list, e.g. inside a:

```
Row {
    spacing: 20
    Repeater {
        model: items
        delegate: ...?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in [`Item.data`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#data-prop):

```
Row {
    spacing: 20
    data: items
}
```